# How to give classes to the corresonding element of the counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

if I want to add a class to the corresponding element of a counter, how would I do that?

I do have something like

```
var li_counter = 0;
   $("#trigger_heritage").click(function () {
        if(heritage_position>=heritage_versatz*13){
            li_counter++;
            $(".heritage_nav" li[li_counter]).addClass("activeheritage");
        }
        else{ // Something else

        }
    });
```

And I want to apply a class to that li-element of the heritage_nav-block
that has the corresponding counterposition. If the user has clicked 5 times, the 5th child-element of heritage_nav shall get the class....

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post your HTML ?

Comment: You're looking for `eq(index)`

Comment: What is `heritage_position` and `heritage_versatz` ? What is that expression means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var li_counter = 0;
   $("#trigger_heritage").click(function () {
        if(heritage_position>=heritage_versatz*13){
            li_counter++;
         $(".heritage_nav li:eq("+li_counter+")").addClass("activeheritage");
        }
        else{ // Something else

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you,

```
var li_counter = 0;
$("#trigger_heritage").click(function () {
    if(heritage_position>=heritage_versatz*13){
        li_counter++;
        $(".heritage_nav").find("li:nth-child(" + li_counter + ")").addClass("activeheritage");

        //if you want to add class to this div
        $(".heritage_nav").addClass("your-class");
    }
    else{ // Something else

    }
});
```